# Update sorted list

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting, microservices, sortedlist

I think there is common name for algorithm I am searching.

I have a big list of players sorted by their score. e.g 1 million or billion players.
Every second one player is changing its score and I wish to updated sorted list to keep it sorted and I wish to know a new player position.

I can update score and re-sort hole list. (not efficient)
or I can re-sort from [oldpos, newpos] (better)
or I can move player and shift other players. (best)

Is there name for such algorithm?

Is that correct that regular databases will not handle that task efficiently and I have to develop service in Java, C#, Go, etc that will keep sorted list in RAM and make shifts?

Comment: regular SQL databases *should* be very good at handling this sort of task efficiently, since a DB index is exactly the kind of data structure you're looking for.  Unfortunately, they are not :(

Answer (score 3):

You can hold an [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), the insertion and deletions operation taken O(logn) time on such data structure. each time you need to update a player: remove from tree, change score, insert to tree.

This is the exact trade-off you are looking for, all the operations takes O(logn) and since you need all the operations (lookup and update - delete\insert) this is the best match for you. The memory consumption is O(n) btw.

Comment: Thank You. I have following concern. If I have 1 million "players" then it would ~20-30 steps deep tree. It would be 2-3 million node allocations. Memory allocation and memory fragmentation may change these expectations? vs int32[1000000] is only 4MB and single allocation. (I can keep all other data in regular database or elsewhere.) I think shifting player IDs in an array might be faster and more predictable. I would prefer to not invent a new algorithm anyway.